# argument in linux to argv

Tags: c, linux

Since I know from C language in Linux if we call int terminal to use C
Example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CDPf.png)

[image]

and from in C file

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

How I must write my code to get from argv in picture to

```
char *av[] = {"cal", "12" , "2021", (char *)0};
```

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the text *as text*.

Comment: As for your problem, any book about C should contain this information, and there must be several thousand tutorials all over the Internet on how to "get" or read the command-line arguments.

Comment: Just ignore `argv[0]`. After `$ ./act41 cal 12 ...` on the command-line, the `argv` elements will point to `argv[0] ==> "./act41"`, `argv[1] ==> "cal"`, `argv[2] ==> "12"`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Since `char *argv[]` contains the program name in element 0 and the program arguments in elements from 1 up, all you have to do to get the desired `av` is declare `char **av = argv+1;`.

Comment: *Since `char *argv[]` contains the program name in element 0...*  Be careful though.  `argv[0]` can be a zero-length string and `argc` is allowed to be zero for no arguments at all.  See [C11 **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2).

Answer (score 0):

Each argument is stored as a character array, so you don't need to worry.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { // equivalent to **argv
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Usage: %s arg1 arg2 arg3\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    char *req_arg1 = argv[1];
    char *req_arg2 = argv[2];
    char *req_arg3 = argv[3];

    // ... manipulation with them ... //

    return 0;
}
```

You can directly use `argv[1]` or `argv[any_valid_position]` whenever required, I just showed how the arguments are separated from each other.

Comment: A usage statement is not an error message.  It would be appropriate to either write `fprintf(stderr, error_msg); exit(1);` or `printf(usage_statement), exit(0);`  Writing a usage statement to stdout and failing is never appropriate.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Now this will exit with the exit code zero.